# suggesstions for a good algorithm and a data structure for efficient calling a function that has tree structured dependencies?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have certain objects that depend on each other. Each object has a costly run function. The dependencies of objects form a graph structure. Any change in object triggers all the dependent objects recursively.

A typical object flow diagram is given below:
[Graph-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDiTN.png)

The arrows represent the flow. SO lets say if the root ds changes, it will trigger all its dependents. In this case v1,v2 once, v3 twice(because of the dependencies/arrows), v4 thrice, and the last DS thrice.

the goal here is that all the objects should only be triggered once. V3 should wait till it receives all the expected updates(we know the expected no of updates because we have the dependencies) and then run once it has all the updates.
It should also accommodate for any change in any other object for example if the root DS changes, and v1 also changes, the expected number of updates would change because the trigger is now coming from two sources

Comment: Assuming the dependency graph is fixed, the straightforward thing to do is to topologically sort the objects so that dependencies always appear before the objects which depend on them; then on each update, iterate through the objects and either reuse the cached value if none of its dependencies have been mutated, or recompute and cache the new value if any of its dependencies have been mutated. Is that "efficient" for your purposes, or do you want to avoid iterating through the whole sequence of objects every time too?

Comment: That isn't a tree, it's a directed graph. A tree does not allow a node to have multiple parents. Representing and traversing a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) is a well-known problem with well-known solutions. It basically happens every time you run a compiler on your code.

Comment: Traversing is fine. When any node changes, it will trigger the dependents recursively. I don't want to change that part. Only when the objects are triggered and the run method is called,  I want to have an algorithm that looks at the dependencies and detects the number of times this object is expected to rerun and make a decision there. Like if it is expected to run multiple times based on the dependencies, then the current run request can be ignored.

Comment: This is a very good paper that discusses various solutions to this problem: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2020/04/build-systems-jfp.pdf

Comment: Thanks all!! I have got an idea of what I need to do. All the comments were really helpful. So thanks Again.